# Can't use string ("6/16") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: linux, perl, hashref

I have a script which has code something like below.

```
$shelf->print("\nStarted syncing from \"${%Family::MEMBERS}{$member}\" \n");
```

When I attempt to run it locally on CentOS 7.0 with perl(v5.8.8) it works fine, however the same code on same OS with perl(v5.16.3) it gives me below error.

```
Can't use string ("6/16") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at
```

I'd appreciate any advise on what changes might have caused this problem, and what the best way would be to fix the script to work correctly in both versions.

Comment: That's indeed wrong. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have updated the code in question, Actually I am printing $member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$BLOCK{EXPR}` accesses an element of the hash referenced by the expression returned by `BLOCK`. Since a reference is expected, the block is evaluated in scalar context. `%Familly::MEMBERS` can't possible result in a reference in scalar context. (It results in a false value or a string describing statistics about the hash.)

---

What you asked:

To print `$member`, you can use

```
print('$member'."\n")
  -or-
print("\$member\n")
```

---

What you could have meant:

To print the value of `$member`, you can use

```
print("$member\n")
```

---

What I think you want:

To access the element of `%Familly::MEMBERS` whose key is the value of `$member`:

```
$Familly::MEMBERS{$member}
```

The fact that you use a fully-qualified name doesn't change anything; the syntax is still `$NAME{EXPR}`.

---

By the way, there's only one "L" in "family".

Comment: Thumbs up for last line. Wanted to write +1 but its not accepting.